# Why predicted values are towards center?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, neural-network, data-science

It looks like most predicted values are close to 0.5. How can the predicted values follow closer the original values?

```
normalizer = layers.Normalization()
normalizer.adapt(np.array(X_train))

model = keras.Sequential([
        normalizer,
        layers.Dense(8, activation='relu'),
        layers.Dense(1, activation='linear'),
        layers.Normalization()
    ])
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Can you explain the intuition behind your model?

Comment: I have 8 data columns and I want to use them to create a single 'valence' prediction. I used a normalization input layer to normalize the input values and a normalization output layer to create a prediction between 0 and 1. The hidden layers are just my experimentation while trying to achieve the above.

Comment: Why normalization layer instead of sigmoid activation function (just curious) ?

Comment: sigmoid output layer produced even more centered values

Comment: loss='mean_absolute_error'. Without normalization or activation function at the output, some values are outside the 0-1 range

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it does not appear to be about programming, but rather statistical modeling.  (This looks like pretty classic underfitting.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There might be many issues here, but definitely you **cannot** normalize data at the output. You are literally saying "on average, I am expecting my output to be 0 and have unit variance". This makes sense iff your target is a standard, normalised Gaussian, but from the plot you can tell clearly it is not. Normalising inputs, or internal activations is fine, as there is always the final layer to apply final affine mapping. But if you do so at the end of the network, you are just making it impossible to learn most targets/signals.

Once this is solved, a network with 8 hidden neurons is **extremely tiny** and there is absolutely no guarantee it can learn anything, your training loss is very far from 0, you should make it much, much more expressive, and try to get your training to 0, if you can't do this - you have a bug somewhere else in the code (or the model is not expressive enough).